# client server communication network programming python

Tags: python, network-programming, client

I Have planned to build an application with a server and multiple clients.When the clients connect to the server for the first time it must be given a id.Each time the client sends a request,the server sends the client a set of strings.the client then processes these strings and once it is done it again sends a request to the server for another set of strings.The strings are present in a database on the server.

I have implemented part of the client program which processes the strings but i don't know how to achieve communication between the server and the clients.

I am developing this application using python.I do not know network programming and hence i dont know how to get this working.

I came upon socket programming and message oriented middleware,message queues,message brokers and am not sure if that is what i need.Could anyone please tell me what i need to use and which topics i need to learn to get this working.I hope that i don't sound vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look at XML-RPC protocol, which allows you to work with proxy objects instead of writing the low-level socket stuff.

Python comes with two modules in the standard library that implements it, the [`xmlprclib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html) implements the client, while [`SimpleXMLRPCServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html) implements the server. In python3 they were renamed to `xmlrpc.client` and `xmlrpc.server`.

Both modules come with [some](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html#example-of-client-usage) [examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#simplexmlrpcserver-example) usages that will probably give you an idea on how to make them work for you.

In particular your server would expose a function to register that client, that returns a new client id, and a function that processes the strings and returns the result, and the clients will simply call that method in the proxy object. It should be pretty simple to implement.

Comment: Thank you ,now i can have functions in my server to register and return id,another to return strings and yet another to receive some responses back from the client as arguments and return nothing.

Comment: @user2078134 The last suggestion I'd give you is to check carefully what objects your functions accept as arguments or return values. In the documentation for the [`ServerProxy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html#xmlrpclib.ServerProxy) there is a table that shows how the types are handled.

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest using something like [beanstalkd](https://github.com/earl/beanstalkc/).

That way you can create a server which pushes 'strings' to a queue and either one or many clients can pull a 'string' from that queue process it and then get another 'string' when they're done.

I believe using queues in this manner is easier than creating sockets etc.

Just taking the example off their website.

Server?

```
>>> import beanstalkc
>>> beanstalk = beanstalkc.Connection(host='localhost', port=14711)
>>> beanstalk.put('hey!')
1
```

Client?

```
>>> job = beanstalk.reserve()
>>> job.body
'hey!'
>>> job.delete()
```

Dead simple to use with the ability to create 'request', 'results', 'error' queues(tubes).

It might not suite your purposes but it's something to bear in mind.